# How to get Id to delete a record using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a list of documents and different actions performed for each records. To delete the record i need the id to pass to the controller. I use JQuery to perform deletion.  In it I need to Id of the record. The Following is my view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".delete_link").live("click", function(e) {
            alert("Hi");
            e.preventDefault();
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")) {

               $.post("/BuildDocument/DeleteBuildDocument", {need to pass id here..});
            }
            else {
                $.post("/BuildDocument/IndexBuildDocument");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<div>
    <div>
        <h1>
            List Build Document</h1>
        <ul>
            <%if (Model.ToList().Count > 0)
              { %>
            <li>
                <br />
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <th align="left">
                            Part No.
                        </th>
                        <th align="left">
                            Issue No
                        </th>
                        <th align="left">
                            Document template
                        </th>
                        <th align="left">
                            Title
                        </th>

                        <th align="center">
                            View
                        </th>
                        <th align="center">
                            Edit
                        </th>
                        <th align="center">
                            Delete
                        </th>

                    </tr>
                    <% foreach (var item in Model)
                       { %>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <%= Html.Encode(item.BldDocPartNo)%>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%= Html.Encode(item.BldDocIssueNo)%>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%= Html.Encode(item.BldDocDocmntTitle)%>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%= Html.Encode(item.BldDocTitle)%>
                        </td>

                        <td align="center">
                            <a href='<%= Url.Action("DetailBuildDocument", "BuildDocument", new { bldDocId = item.BldDocId })%>'>
                                <img src="../../html/images/edit-icon.gif" alt="edit" border="0" /></a>                               
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                            <a href='<%= Url.Action("EditBuildDocument", "BuildDocument", new { bldDocId = item.BldDocId })%>'>
                                <img src="../../html/images/Edit.gif" alt="edit" border="0" /></a>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">                               
                           <%--<%= Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteBuildDocument", new { bldDocId = item.BldDocId }, new {@class ="delete-link" })%>--%>
                            <a>
                                <img src="../../html/images/inst-delete-ico.gif" alt="delete" border="0" /></a>
                        </td>                          
                    </tr>
                    <% } %>
                </table>
            </li>
            <%} %>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>


$.post("/BuildDocument/DeleteBuildDocument", {need to pass id here..});
```

need the id(BldDocId). How can i get it?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: please check some answers to your previous answers. It is a way to say "thank you" here.

Answer (score 1):

```
        $(".delete_link").live("click", function(e) {
            var $link = $(this);
            alert("Hi");
            e.preventDefault();
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")) {

               $.post("/BuildDocument/DeleteBuildDocument", { var id = $link.attr('bldDocId'); });
            }
            else {
                $.post("/BuildDocument/IndexBuildDocument");
            }
        });
```

Comment: I tried as follows: var id = $(".delete_link").attr('BldDocId'); alert(id); //var id = $link.attr('id'); var id = $(".delete_link").attr('id'); alert(id); 1st alert box showed "undefined" and 2st alert box was empty.

Comment: @Suja: also, there is no any `bldDocId` in your **html**.

Comment: @Suja: omg, why do you ignore my answer? use `$(this)` to get current element as I did in my code.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    $(".delete_link").live("click", function(e) {
            var $link = $(this);
            alert("Hi");
            e.preventDefault();
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")) {
               $.post("/BuildDocument/DeleteBuildDocument", { var id = $link.attr('id'); });
            }
            else {
                $.post("/BuildDocument/IndexBuildDocument");
            }
        });

    </script>
When i gave this I didn't recieve the even the 1st alert box with "hi". Also at "var id" error : "Expected identifier or string".

Comment: $.post("/BuildDocument/DeleteBuildDocument", { id: $link.attr('id') }); 
This took me inside DeleteBuildDocument in controller, but id was empty.

Comment: The problem with your answer is that the bldDocId is not an attribute but a *route parameter*. I'd just use a hidden field next to the link and do $link.parent().find('.myHiddenField').val()

Comment: @sirrocco: it is a problem with question, not with answer. I pointed him that he has not bldDocId in html.

Comment: I agree, but if you didn't show him how to write it - your answer didn't help much, right ?

Comment: @sirrocco: my answer at least gives him a hint about how to get current item, that was triggered an event.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know asp.net.
But it seems the class name is "delete-link", from

```
new {@class ="delete-link"}
```

If my mistake, ignore me.